# Linux sound: play back audio from input only on specific output device

Tags: audio, alsa, recording

I currently have a shairport (AirPlay) server which receives audio data and outputs it over optical SP/DIF (Toslink) via a USB-to-Toslink adapter.

This digital signal goes through an equalizer, and comes back into the Linux box via a Toslink input port, on another USB sound card.

I would like this Toslink input to be played on a third device: a USB DAC.

Here is the signal path:

shairport -> USB-to-Toslink -> Behringer DEQ2496 -> USB-Toslink-input -> USB-DAC-output

In other words, I would like to play two separate audio streams on each their device: 1) the shairport output should play on the USB-to-Toslink card and 2) the USB-Toslink-input signal should play on the USB-DAC output.

How do I do that?

I know I can use `aplay -D` to play an audio stream on a specific ALSA device, but it requires that I specify bit depth, sample rate and format. I'm looking for a higher level solution, where the input on one device is just routed to another device. All devices in question support up to 24 bit/96 KHz, so only sample format conversion is necessary.

Comment: You don't mention Jack and you may have good reasons to use Alsa and not Jack, but this sound like a typical Jack usage. I think most people doing music with a Linux box use Jack. (I didn't check Jack support for your specific devices.)

Comment: I have looked at Jack, and as far as I can see it doesn't do what I need. As far as I can see, Jack is concerned with inter-application routing. ALSA is the kernel interface to specific devices, as far as I understand. Jack uses ALSA to output audio to a specific device.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. Jack can route audio flows between multiple hardware devices, not only softwares. I think it could route shairport to USB-to-Toslink and USB-Toslink-input to USB-DAC output independently. Again, I may be wrong, but it might be worth a try. At least you may check its compatibility with your hardware elements.

Comment: The Shairport is independent. You just need some software to record from the Toslink input and play this data back on the DAC. Both Jack and PulseAudio should be able to do that.